# How to SELECT with two condition using OR clause

Tags: php, mysql

I have a database table with the following structure and data:

```
| username | content                  | date               |
  elgrand    hello                      2013-08-08 17:04:07
  alphard    hey,how are you elgrand?   2013-08-08 17:50:22
  elyson     I don't have any idea      2013-08-08 18:14:31
```

Is it POSSIBLE to select ALL of row where the username is 'elgrand' + ALL of row where the content is containing word 'elgrand'
and the result will be sort by date as DESCENDING ??

I've tried this but seems there is something wrong with the query and wasn't really ORDERED BY the date, and sometimes the result are double.

```
SELECT * FROM ms_writing 
         WHERE username='elgrand' OR content LIKE '%elgrand%' 
         ORDER BY date DESC
```

Comment: Use `AND` instead of `OR`

Comment: The results can never be double when you are selecting from a single table.

Comment: The query as you've written it seems to work OK with the sample data you've posted. [Here's a SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d84bcb/1). Maybe you could provide more details on the problems you had with this, or a demo that demonstrates them?

Answer (score 1):

You need an `AND` -

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    ms_writing 
WHERE 
    username = 'elgrand' AND 
    content LIKE '%elgrand%' 
ORDER BY 
    date DESC
```

This query will return all rows whose username is `elgrand` and whose content has the string `elgrand`.

Comment: this result null because this will select a row which username is 'elgrand' and it content contains word 'elgrand'

Comment: As I understand the question, "AND ALSO", although poorly phrased, means that the OP wants to select rows that contains the 'elgrand' name OR rows that contains 'elgrand' in the contents, therefore the query in the question should return the expected result

Answer (score 0):

Please use `AND` instead `OR`

`SELECT * FROM ms_writing WHERE username='elgrand' AND content LIKE '%elgrand%' ORDER BY date DESC`

Results never double until 2 records have same data

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use AND instead of OR. So your query will be:

```
SELECT * FROM ms_writing 
         WHERE username='elgrand' AND content LIKE '%elgrand%' 
         ORDER BY date DESC
```

Plus one thing for your information, not to use reserve words as a database field name, e.g date,order etc. It might create a sort of ambiguity.